# Google Cloud Composer Worker has high CPU Usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, airflow

We are currently debugging issues in Google Cloud Composer, more specifically single worker-nodes in the underlying GKE cluster consuming well above 100% of their allocated CPU credits.

By inspecting the pods running on the affected nodes and selectively killing them by hand we identified the `airflow-worker` Pod being the culprit. Once we kill the Pod and have it reassigned to a different node, the CPU usage goes back to normal levels. We also verified we have no compute-intensive tasks running at all, in fact, even though there are no active DAG runs at all during certain times, the CPU usage still stays high.

We inspected the logs outputted by the `airflow-worker` Pod and noticed it keeps syncing the DAG definitions from GCS in seemingly an endless loop, which we currently suspect might be causing the high CPU load. Is there a way to reduce this interval to a minute or less often? Our Airflow deployment has `dag_dir_list_interval` set to `100` which does not seem to change any behavior.

```
I 2020-07-23T17:28:03.562328926Z Syncing GCS bucket.
I 2020-07-23T17:28:03.562404454Z Syncing dags directory...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:04.188896476Z Building synchronization state...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:04.425299277Z Starting synchronization...
I 2020-07-23T17:28:04.508996248Z Syncing plugins directory...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:05.148325664Z Building synchronization state...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:05.333753680Z Starting synchronization...
I 2020-07-23T17:28:05.439193209Z Finished syncing.
I 2020-07-23T17:28:15.440788248Z Syncing GCS bucket.
I 2020-07-23T17:28:15.440829226Z Syncing dags directory...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:16.072741276Z Building synchronization state...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:16.294787540Z Starting synchronization...
I 2020-07-23T17:28:16.386285332Z Syncing plugins directory...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:17.006720311Z Building synchronization state...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:17.180710366Z Starting synchronization...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:17.189223264Z Removing file:///home/airflow/gcs/plugins/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
E 2020-07-23T17:28:17.189817529Z Removing file:///home/airflow/gcs/plugins/__pycache__/base_bigquery_stream_operator.cpython-36.pyc
E 2020-07-23T17:28:17.192383078Z Removing file:///home/airflow/gcs/plugins/__pycache__/bigquery_to_pubsub.cpython-36.pyc
E 2020-07-23T17:28:17.193982280Z Removing file:///home/airflow/gcs/plugins/__pycache__/bigquery_to_sqs.cpython-36.pyc
I 2020-07-23T17:28:17.272811680Z Finished syncing.
I 2020-07-23T17:28:27.273965888Z Syncing GCS bucket.
I 2020-07-23T17:28:27.274042577Z Syncing dags directory...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:27.895370956Z Building synchronization state...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:28.071289313Z Starting synchronization...
I 2020-07-23T17:28:28.161823851Z Syncing plugins directory...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:28.790080974Z Building synchronization state...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:28.971916630Z Starting synchronization...
I 2020-07-23T17:28:29.051574160Z Finished syncing.
I 2020-07-23T17:28:39.053008583Z Syncing GCS bucket.
I 2020-07-23T17:28:39.053095341Z Syncing dags directory...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:39.704627585Z Building synchronization state...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:39.878830483Z Starting synchronization...
I 2020-07-23T17:28:39.964607913Z Syncing plugins directory...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:40.587001820Z Building synchronization state...
E 2020-07-23T17:28:40.757289540Z Starting synchronization...
I 2020-07-23T17:28:40.835296305Z Finished syncing.
```

Answer (score -1):

To overcome this problem, please follow the steps below:

```
1- Continue to modify resource/limits
2- Increase the machine size [1]
3- Split DAGs into separate Composer environments
```

[1]
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/updating#upgrading_the_machine_type

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Upgrading resources would be an option, given the DAGs are mostly idle in our small environment I don´t think this is the case though. We added more nodes to the cluster and have overprovisioned the CPU on the machines significantly and are still seeing this issue.